# What is the ws://?

Tags: javascript, ajax, protocols, stackexchange

I was inspecting the stackoverflow pages for curiosity and noticed that interesting url: `ws://sockets-se.or.stackexchange.com/`

[image]

I would like to know more about the ws protocol but I don't even know how to start searching because searching for `ws` or `ws protocol` is not showing me the results that I was expecting...

What is this protocol? Can someone point me to a direction?

Comment: [Web Sockets](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6455#section-3)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`ws:` This is the new URL schema for WebSocket connections. There is also `wss:` for secure WebSocket connection the same way `https:` is used for secure HTTP connections.

## By Definition

The WebSocket specification defines an API establishing "socket" connections between a web browser and a server.

## In plain words

There is an persistent connection between the client and the server and both parties can start sending data at any time. That is a full-duplex communication channels over a single TCP connection.

Take a look **[here](http://dev.w3.org/html5/websockets/)**  for API and  **[here](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/websockets/basics/)** for web sockets basics and 
**[here](http://html5demos.com/web-socket)** for a simple live demo of it.

Answer (score 9):

ws:// is the URI scheme for [WebSockets](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSocket).  They provide full-duplex communications over a single TCP connection.  You often see them used for asynchronous streaming of data to the browser... for say, a chat application or a browser-based game.

Consequently, because it's used for streaming data, clicking the Response tab in the Chrome Developer Tools won't show you data for the connection like you'd expect.  Chrome, for example, would show you the "frames" sent over the connection with their given directionality, etc.

Answer (score 3):

This is for the `websocket` protocol

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSocket

https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6455

Other documents you can find if you use a searchengine and search for `Websockets`